# ¿Está roomba activo en Stack Overflow en español?

Tags: soporte, eliminación-de-preguntas

De acuerdo a [El usuario "Comunidad" ha eliminado mi pregunta. ¿Qué pasó?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) ciertas preguntas deberían eliminarse automáticamente pero parece que eso no está ocurriendo. Por ejemplo la siguiente búsqueda devuelve más de 4k preguntas

[Preguntas abiertas con puntuación menor igual a 0 creadas antes del 2018-06 con 0 respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=created%3A..2018-06+answers%3A0+votes%3A...0+is%3Aq+closed%3A0)

¿Estoy pasando algo por alto o es simplemente que roomba no está activado en Stack Overflow en español?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[El enlace que das](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) contiene la respuesta:

> Si la pregunta tiene más de 365 dias de antigüedad y...
>
> - puntuación de 0, o puntuación de 1 y la cuenta del propietario está eliminada.
> - no tiene ninguna respuesta
> - no está bloqueada
> - tiene un número de vistas <= 1,5 veces la edad de pregunta (en días).
> - tiene uno o ningún comentario.
>
> ... será borrada automáticamente. A este tipo de preguntas se las llama "abandonadas" (`RemoveAbandonedQuestions`).

He mirado unas cuantas de las preguntas que salen en [Preguntas abiertas con puntuación menor igual a 0 creadas antes del 2018-06 con 0 respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=created%3A..2018-06+answers%3A0+votes%3A...0+is%3Aq+closed%3A0) y en todas ellas veo unos cuantos comentarios, por la cual cosa uno de los puntos no se cumple y evita que Roomba actúe.

Si das algún ejemplo específico podemos mirarlo con calma, pues [Roomba a veces tiene pequeños síncopes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335884/1983854).

Comment: Gracias. Se me había pasado lo de tiene uno o ningún comentario. Los que he visto tienen tres o mas